# Prosody muc chat history is not complete

Tags: lua, xmpp, prosody-im, strophe.js

I try to make conference chat using prosody, and for the client I use strophe.js. Everything works great except one thing that the chat history shown to user when they just join in to the room is not complete. For example:
One client has already sent messages to the room like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But when new client join in to the room, they only get messages like this:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

I try to set `max_history_messages = 10` in prosody config, and set `maxstanzas = 10` from client. But still the same.

Here is my config file

```
admins = { "agent@localhost" }
modules_enabled = {
        "message_logging";
        "roster";
        "saslauth";
        "tls";
        "dialback";
        "disco"; 

        "private";
        "vcard";

        "version";
        "uptime";
        "time";
        "ping";
        "pep";
        "register";

        "admin_adhoc";
        "admin_telnet";

        "bosh";

        "posix";
};

bosh_ports = { 5280 }
bosh_max_inactivity = 60
consider_bosh_secure = true
cross_domain_bosh = true
http_paths = {
        bosh = "/http-bind"; -- Serve BOSH at /http-bind
        files = "/"; -- Serve files from the base URL
    }

allow_registration = true;

daemonize = true;

pidfile = "/var/run/prosody/prosody.pid";

ssl = {
    key = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.key";
    certificate = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.crt";
}

c2s_require_encryption = false

s2s_secure_auth = false

authentication = "internal_plain"

log = {
    info = "/var/log/prosody/prosody.log";
    error = "/var/log/prosody/prosody.err";
    { levels = { "error" }; to = "syslog";  };
}

VirtualHost "localhost"
    enabled = true -- Remove this line to enable this host
    ssl = {
        key = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.key";
        certificate = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.crt";
    }

Component "conference.localhost" "muc"
    restrict_room_creation = true
    max_history_messages = 10

Include "conf.d/*.cfg.lua"
```

Is there something need to set in config?

Here's how I handle message in Strophe.js:

```
function onLoginComplete(status) {
    console.log(status);
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
        console.log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
        console.log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
        console.log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
        console.log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        console.log('Strophe is connected.');
        connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null, null);

    if (!chat_room) {
      // join to chatroom
    }
}

/**
* on new message handler
**/
function onMessage(message) {
    console.log(message);
    var type = $(message).attr('type');
    var body = $(message).find('body').text();
    switch (type) {
    case 'groupchat':
        console.log(body);
        // todo append message to the list
        appendMessage(message);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's one message of the history when user just join the room:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat"     to="subkhan@localhost/edff55f2-2980-4d01-bf65-0d2c0b011845"     from="test@conference.localhost/subkhan"><body>8</body><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2017-04-12T02:54:48Z"></delay><x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20170412T02:54:48"></x></message>
```

Is there something to do with the delay?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, all this time client already gets all the complete messages history, except it goes to `rawInput(data)`, not to `onMessage()` handler. So I just remove the handler and handle the incoming message through `rawInput(data)`.